# i cannot send mail on unix aix?

Tags: email, unix, command-line-interface, aix

i try to send e-mail but the following error appear :-

`bbb@ccc.com... User unknown`

`/dead.letter... Saved message in /dead.letter`

how i can solve this error ????

Comment: "bbb@ccc.com" local email address?

Comment: yes it is local email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found a similar problem on Unix.com forums, where someone was also receiving the dead.letter issue. Have you configured sendmail? If not, in the configuration file /etc/sendmail.cf, the line with DS must be modified and you must specified your mail server. 
You can add this server in the file /etc/host.

After the modification of your sendmail configuration, you restart the service :

## refresh -s sendmail

or

## stopsrc -s sendmail

## startsrc -s sendmail -a "-bd"

HTH,

Rachel

Comment: Also try sending mail from the command line with logging on (ie: mail -vvv -s Test root < /dev/null )